# Extracting Prime Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I need to create a method that will mark the prime numbers and return the count of the prime numbers.

I went this far:

```
  private static int[] extractPrimesNumbers(int[] array, int countOfPrimeNumbers) {
        int[] primeNumber = new int[countOfPrimeNumbers];
        int position = 0;
        for (int j = 2; j < array.length; j++) {
            for(int key : array) {
                if(j == 2) {
                    array[position] = j;
                }
                boolean isDividedByJ = j % j == 0;
                boolean isDividedbyTwo = j % 2 != 0;
                if(isDividedByJ && isDividedbyTwo) {
                    array[position] = j;
                    position++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
```

I don't know how to mark none prime numbers. I was thinking the good way is marking the none prime with 0, then calculate the amount of value from position/index which are higher than 0.
Worth to mention this all things needs to be in one method using array. Can't use any standard solution for Prime using external boolean methods.

Comment: Can you please give some examples inputs with their expected outputs?

Comment: Hi, So I have an array of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] and I need to have [3, 5, 7, 9, 11 etc]

Answer (score 0):

just return an array of the numbers that are prime, no need to mark. and the diff in the cont of the new array and the old one gives you a cont of the non prime as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution approach.

1) First crete a very simple method to check whether a number is prime or not. See below:

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println(number);

    for (int i=2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
        if(number % i == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;

}
```

2) Create another method that will loop through your array and call the above method:

```
public static int numOfPrimesInArray(int[] arr){
    int counter = 0;
    for (int num: arr){
        if (checkPrime(num)) counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

3) Then simply call this from your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] nums = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int primes = numOfPrimesInArray(nums);
    System.out.println(primes);
}
```

If I did not make any mistake when writing this shoul give you the number of primes in your array.

Comment: Like I mention in the description I can''t use external boolean methods.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with Python. I tried a couple of alternatives and this one is the quickest. Still, I encountered a memory overflow at 1000000.

```
n = int(input("Type a number"))
primes = 0
for j in range(2,n+1):
 
    for k in range(2,j):
        if j%k==0:
            primes = primes +1
            #print(j)
            break
    
        
print(n-1-primes)
```